# Is it possible to add the all scan base packages into spring.factories file in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I have a more than one spring boot modules. There is a dependency for each other modules. For each project has a module. Here I dont want to use `@CamponentScan("com.myapp.register,com.module.admin")` or `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.myapp.register","com.module.admin"})`
in my project. Because if in future if we want add one more base package i dont want go for above approach.

If any other way to add the base packages in our package. 
I thought **spring.factories** is better for this. I mean this is also same like properties files. spring.factories is configure the auto configuration. But i dont know how to add the base packages into that file.

I saw some examples in few tutorials, they provide only configuration classes only.

I done this way but still we need to use `@ComponentScan` in my code. I dont want this approch.

I want to add the all the base packages into the **spring.factories** 
is it possible? If it is possible plese provide solution and sample way for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is the purpose of `spring.factories` file. If you want to develop your modules with Auto Configuring capabilities then you can go for that. For that you can use following tutorials [Spring Boot Auto Configuration 1](https://www.techtalks.lk/blog/2018/5/debunking-the-magic-behind-spring-boot) and [Spring Boot Auto Configuration 2](https://www.techtalks.lk/blog/2018/7/debunking-the-magic-behind-spring-boot-2).

In your case you can either stick a similar package naming convention like `com.myapp.module` and can have `@ComponentScan("com.myapp.module.*")`.